# Pass two parameters as one to TWIG url

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I'm using a framework (specifically EC-Cube3, if interested) that uses a Silex application with TWIG templates.

It has a navigation sidebar that is configured with PHP object arrays. I can inject an item array that looks something like this:

```
$item = array(
    "id" => "item_id"
    "url" => "named_url"
);
```

The url is created in typical Silex fashion:

```
$app->match('/item', 'Controller::method')->bind('named_url');
```

The framework eventually uses the `url` field and evaluates it in TWIG like so:

`{{ url(item.url) }}`

And this is usually fine! But the problem comes when I have a URL that includes a parameter, like this:

```
$app->match('/item/{id}', 'Controller::method')->bind('named_url'); // Needs 'id' to be evaluated.
```

In this scenario, setting the URL by the same array won't work because TWIG's `url` function needs the `id` for the second argument.

Since I can't change the application's TWIG files (because then I can't safely update the application), I need to be able to set the item's `url` to include the `id` as well.

After investigating, I don't think this is possible. Is it true that this is impossible? Or is there some method that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutiple vars like this

`{{ path('path_in_route', {'id': article.id,'slug': article.slug}) }}`

And 
`path_in_route`
 must be in your router file.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I can easily do it by editing the twig files, but I can't. I can only edit the PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following in your Twig file:

```
{{ url(item.url,{'id': id}) }}
```

I believe that should work, but not certain.

---

EDIT #2

What if you use something like this:

```
$app->match('/item', 'Controller::method($id)')->bind('named_url');
```

Where `$id` is the id you need to pass in. I'm not really familiar with Silex, but maybe it's something like that?

Comment: Same thing here. I can't edit the twig files. I can only edit the PHP array.

Comment: See my EDIT #2 changes.

Comment: That's certainly interesting. I like thinking outside the box here. Removing `id` from the route would certainly allow TWIG to resolve the URL, but that would lose the flexibility of the variable in the route.

Put simply, this would only allow the single URL of `/item` to match, and other URLs like `/item/3` would no longer match.

Silex wouldn't be able to connect URLs like that to the controller method.